# Combining two lex/yacc solutions

Tags: bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

In order to get a *complete solution* for parsing and analysing an ***embedded sql code*** I'd like to know if it is possible to combine two **lex|yacc** solutions, one for Ansi C and the other for SQL, in the same program. I assume there will be a kind of orchestration between the two grammars.

Sorry if my idea is a little bit ambiguous; as far as proposals come I'll explain more my point of view.

So first of all, my question is: can a parsing solution(**lex|yacc** or **flex|bison**) contain **more than one lex** file and also the same question for a yacc file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the -P option to add a prefix to the generated code and to the file names.

For more information, google for "lex yacc prefix".

Comment: for a first view it's only for Flex and Bison solution not for lex and yacc.

Comment: I see some confusing answers in this identical question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730029/is-it-possible-to-have-two-or-more-lex-yacc-parsers-in-the-same-application.  Some say that POSIX requires yacc to implement the -p option.  Others say that only Flex and Bison support it, not Lex and yacc.  You may want to check that other question for more details.